# How to repeat VIM surround with HTML tag on Visual mode

Tags: linux, unix, vim, plugins

According to [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), we can do the following:

```
Finally, let's try out visual mode. 
Press a capital V (for linewise visual mode) followed by S<p class="important">.
```

And you get this

```
<p class="important">
  <em>Hello</em> world!
</p>
```

I tried and it works. But how can I repeat that command on many other
visual blocks? I tried `.` but didn't work.

**Update:**

With this text:

```
foo
foo
foo
```

I tried this `qqgvS<p class="important">q`. It correctly gives

```
<p class="important">
foo
</p>
foo
foo
```

But when I repeat with this `@q` (with cursor on *f* letter of second row) it gives this:

```
<p>
<p class="important">
foo
</p>
</p>
foo
foo
```

Instead of

```
<p class="important">
foo
</p>
<p class="important">
foo
</p>
foo
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I usually do that with something like:

```
:'<,'>norm! yss<p>
```

As an alternative, you could record a macro and play it back on each line.

Answer (score 3):

You can't; the *repeat.vim* plugin only handles repetition from normal mode. I've written a companion [visualrepeat plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3848), but *surround.vim* doesn't support that.

For built-in commands, you could execute on a visual selection via `gv:normal .<CR>`, but that doesn't work here, neither.

The only option I see is recording a macro, and then executing that on each previous selection (via use of `gv`).

Comment: how do you do that with macro?

Comment: Basically, `qqgvS<p class="important">q`. Then, select the line(s), and trigger via `<Esc>@q`.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't seem to work. See my update.

Comment: Repeat only works _after_ having done a visual selection, not in normal mode. So, select line(s) first, then `<Esc>@q`.